# Error when creating custom seaborn colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to create my own colormap object for a seaborn heatmap.

But when I type in:

```
import seaborn as sns
new_map = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1907), it is a *bug* which you can solve by downgrading `numpy` to a version prior to `1.18`:

```
pip install numpy==1.17.4
```

or upgrade seaborn to a version newer than 0.9.1:

```
pip install seaborn==1.10.0
```